# Is there a way integrate Python with Cordovafor front end development?

Tags: python, cordova

I am currently learning python's OpenCV module. I thought it would be great to create an android app to implement the image processing techniques. The first option was Kivy, but it would take a long time for me to learn and create an app in Kivy. Cordova is my choice for the app since it simply is just HTML. Since image processing is totally front end, I was wondering, if it's possible to use Cordova along with Python for this purpose?

**EDIT**

I just want to make a simple android application, that uses the device's camera and apply some filters to the camera frame.

Comment: The question is quite broad. Please add more details about what you're trying to achieve (what sort of processing, why you need OpenCV in the first place etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat generic, so here's my take:

IMHO the only way to integrate OpenCV in your app is to write a [plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html).

However, you could possibly separate the processing and create a backend OpenCV and your frontend in Cordova (get the processed image off the backend).

Comment: I for once, thought about processing the frame on the back end but, since I want real-time processing, it's not going to be a good idea. Will surely look into plugin development.